# Enabling windows azure tools to get Windows Azure project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am trying to create a webproject which can be deployed on azure. I have VS 2010 trial version (pro) installed on windows 7. When i click cloud (under VC#) i am prompted to install Windows azure tools. I do this. I get the tools installed message. I restart VS 2010. But i fail to find windows azure web project template, which should have been installed. It just shows me the same sequence of screens (install tools etc). I am executing VS 2010 under administrator role.

Steps described @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff687127.aspx

Questions

1. Is Windows azure template projects not allowed in Trial edition of VS 2010 pro?
2. Can such a project be made using VS 2010 express?

Thank you

Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about trial versions, as I've never tried installing with a trial edition. However: I've run other software packages with trial versions of Visual Studio, without issue.

The SDK will work with Visual Studio 2010 Pro and above, as well as Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (downloadable [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express)).

For installing the tools properly, I'd suggest going [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/) and installing via Web Platform Installer. It will make sure you have all needed dependencies.

Comment: Reinstalled web developer express after uninstalling VS2010 pro (trial). Now i can see the windows azure project template. Thank you Sameer